# Align Text in Center of TextView in Linear Layout inside of Framelayout

Tags: android

I am trying to place text of a text view in center. I already have used layout_gravity="center" but it appears of no use. Can anyone suggest me what is wrong in the below code. Please note, I have to use framelayout and Linear Layout inside it. This cannot be changed. Min SDK Version is 11.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.SKSDroid.notifydaily.NotifyDaily" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/black_overlay"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="UselessParent" >


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:text="@string/dummy_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="#33b5e5"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/autorTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:text="Sonu"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="#33b5e5"
android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `android:gravity="centre"`